# The meaning of computer:///

Tags: nautilus, files, gvfs, location

I would like to know the meaning of  **computer:///**

How to go with the command line to a file at location  **computer:///**

Comment: Where did you encounter this?

Comment: you can see it your File Manager, if you use thunar, the path for trash & network are given as: **:///**

Comment: @Nmath  There is such protocol, and it's not just related to Ubuntu. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `computer:///` scheme is [provided by GVfs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/schemes):

> List of drives, volumes and mounts

That's all it really means. It's one of the schemes understood by the file manager. The Ubuntu's file manager Nautilus is built using Gtk,Gio, and GVfs libraries, hence why such uri scheme is available. Others, such as [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM_Roadmap) also support it. In general, this is known as [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) which originally was meant for web technologies. Interestingly enough, some of the ideas are used on desktop as well. URI is one example, while [GSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) use fully qualified domain name scheme, similar to how DNS would resolve a website.

Note, however, that the original GVfs link suggests `computer:///` uri may be deprecated eventually. And exactly because Nautilus uses Gio/GVfs, this syntax is understood. If a file manager or another application are built with Qt for example, there's no guarantee it will be understood there.

> How to go with the command line to a file at location computer:///

You can't, unless you write a command-line application that uses Gio/GVfs and recognizes `computer:///` uri scheme. It's a virtual location, and doesn't have a real directory associated with it, so we can't simply `cd` into it in shell. Since the description states that it's basically a list of drives, volumes, and mountpoints it is sufficient to use `lsblk` command to get a *listing* of block devices and associated mountpoints

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0    28G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    28G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 111.8G  0 part /mnt/ubuntu
```

List of drives ? Use `udisksctl status`

```
$ udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CHN 25SATA01M 030         P0527A    30CG09180078         sda     
Radeon R7                 1.01      A22MD061520000172    sdb
```

If you need a very lengthy and detailed listing, there's also `udisksctl dump`